# Drawing Triangles in WPF with Mouse Drag

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm attempting to make a very very simple paint project in C#'s WPF.  I have pretty much everything working except for drawing a triangle.  I can't figure out the math required to create the triangle.

I have code like this for drawing rectangles and circles:

```
case "Rectangle":
case "Ellipse":
    var x = Math.Min(pos.X, mm.startPoint.X);
    var y = Math.Min(pos.Y, mm.startPoint.Y);

    var width = Math.Max(pos.X, mm.startPoint.X) - x;
    var height = Math.Max(pos.Y, mm.startPoint.Y) - y;

    mm.shapeObj.Width = width;
    mm.shapeObj.Height = height;

    Canvas.SetLeft(mm.shapeObj, x);
    Canvas.SetTop(mm.shapeObj, y);
    break;
```

I add it to the children of the canvas elsewhere.  This code allows me to click on the canvas and drag my mouse to size the rectangle or ellipse.

I was hoping to do something similar with a triangle.  I only want the user to be able to click on the screen and drag out an equilateral triangle, for simplicity sake.  I thought about making it so the user could just click three times to create the triangle but due to the way the project is coded, that would be a little more difficult than it sounds.  However, if there isn't any way to calculate the triangle I'm trying to create, I can make it work with three clicks.

Comment: So, what do you need? The coordinates of the three vertices? What is the startpoint? center of the triangle or one of the vertices?

Answer (score 2):

if you order your points like this:

```
int smX = startPoint.X < finalPoint.X ? startPoint.X : finalPoint.X;
int bgX = startPoint.X < finalPoint.X ? finalPoint.X : startPoint.X;

int smY = startPoint.Y < finalPoint.Y ? startPoint.Y : finalPoint.Y;
int bgY = startPoint.Y < finalPoint.Y ? finalPoint.Y : startPoint.Y;
```

You can imagine a rectangle with the points:

```
(smX, smY)
(smX, bgY)
(bgX, smY)
(bgX, bgY)
```

So you could use the middle of the rectangle to set a point of triangle, than draw a triangle with the points:

```
(smX, bgY)
(bgX, bgY)
(smX + ((bgX - smX) / 2), smY)
```

Comment: I get this part. I know how to draw the triangle.  The problem is I don't have static x and y positions like they do in that example.  I only know the point where the user clicked and where they're dragging the mouse and I need to form an equilateral triangle with that.

Comment: Done :) sorry for interpret wrongly in first answer.

Comment: Didn't even think of something like this! Thank you, this should work perfectly.